# Ask Microsoft for features

Tags: visual-studio, request

How does one make a feature request for Visual Studio to Microsoft?

Comment: First you need to find a suitable altar and a newborn goat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft's product feedback web site can be found at http://connect.microsoft.com/

For Visual Studio specifically, the link is http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Answer (score 7):

That's what [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/) is for in particular the [feedback forum for Visual Studio](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

They are quite fast with fixing bugs, but suggestions... You never know how much you will be heard.